# Web Socket Connection closed with status code 1006 (SignalR)

Tags: push-notification, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using signalR alongwith quartz in my asp .net core 2.1 web application. App is running perfect on localhost.Bu getting an error on mostly machines which is "WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ()". Connection to signalR automatically lost and established again on refresh the page.